# How to list all entries in Deno KV?

Tags: key-value, deno, key-value-store

I don't see an example on [Operations | Deno Docs](https://docs.deno.com/deploy/kv/manual/operations#list). I don't know where I've missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To list all entries simply use an empty prefix. E.g.

```
const allEntries = await Array.fromAsync(kv.list({prefix:[]}));
```

Comment: hmm, why does it need [`Array.fromAsync()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fromAsync "Array.fromAsync() - JavaScript | MDN")? The docs doesn't help me understand. In contrast, `kv.get(['path', 'to', 'key'])` doesn't require it

Comment: kv.list returns an async iterator which is used to retrieve remote entries. Array.fromAsync is just syntactic sugar to irritate over and collect the results from the async iterator, whereas kv.get returns a single entry.

Comment: You could also skip the Array.fromAsync using the longer form: `const entriesIterator = kv.list({ prefix: ["my prefix"] });
for await (const entry of entriesIterator) {...}

Comment: Yes, the benefit of [`for await...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of) is that it's there are many entries then it will iterate over them lazily while never storing all entries in memory at once (internal buffer and paging). If you know there aren't a ton of entries though then loading them all into memory at once isn't an issue.

Comment: You can also control the batch size used internally for pagination: https://deno.land/api@v1.41.3?s=Deno.KvListOptions&unstable=#prop_batchSize

Comment: Can you explain what the [async iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncIterator) does. I read the docs and still have no idea. Why can't the server simply return the array?

Comment: @Ooker, when you list from KV it doesn't pull back everything at once. Instead it pulls results in batches (size is configurable). Thus, you iterate over results in an asynchronous manner as some iterations will fetch data. This allows you to process data as you retrieve it and not have to wait until it is all fetched.

Comment: Ah, so normally when pulling an array it will pull individual element in it? And `kv.list` is actually not an array to optimize data size?

Comment: In essence, it's not pulling an array but iterating over a remote data source. You could view KV as one giant array and list iterates over a sub section of that. It would be inefficient to have to wait until all data was downloaded before using it. Thus the async iterator to allow downloading AND processing at the same time.